# How can I implement undo functionality in my painting application for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, undo

I developed a painting application for iPad. I have tried in many ways to implement undo functionality in my app, but I couldn't. I tried to save every drawing object as an image by capturing the screen in the `touchesEnd:` method. I can save all these drawn objects in an array and while doing undo I can display the previous drawn object image by adding it as a subview of my drawing view. Until now, it has been working fine, but after adding that image to my view I couldn't draw any more. I have enabled the `userInteraction` property for the `ImageView`, also, but I still couldn't draw.

How can I change that `ImageView` to allow drawing after doing undo?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create core data objects for your drawing operations and then use the core data undo manager.
Have  a look here:
http://www.mikeabdullah.net/core_data_undo_management.html